# Understand interaction in nested design

Tags: linear-model

I'm trying to understand the output in r for nested factors in a linear model:

lm(weight~A/B)

Let's say A is the brandname of two different manufacturers and B are the products which are unique to the manufacturers, i.e. manufacturer 1 produces product a and b and only he does.

As an output of drop1(test="F"), I get significant "interactions" for this, but not for the main effects. Can someone please explain to me the nature of these "interactions"? Interactions as I understand them can't happen here because each product is only produced by one manufacturer and thus can not have different effects over the two manufacturers.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand it now, a significant A:B output means that B has a significant effect while being nested in A, but not that there are interactions.